# Is there a specific way to interact with Ryzen CPUs in Python to find their wattage usage? Specifically Ryzen 7000 series?

Tags: python, c#, .net, amd-processor

I have found ways to see the real-time wattage of my Ryzen 9 7900X3D in programs such as Ryzen Master or open source programs such as LibreHardWareMonitor. However, these are only GUIs and visual interfaces that don't have cloud functions as far as I know. I want to use a python program to monitor my wattage usage on my pc. This way I can model by expected electricty costs per month.

Using this monitoring system I will use a python library gspread to interact with Google Sheets and send my results periodicity where I can access it on a smartphone or another pc while I am away from my pc, or at the end of a work day.

I've already done this in python with subprocesses accessing nvidia-smi for monitoring my wattage on my RTX 4070. I just am lost with my CPU.

My thought process so far (my only development experience is web based applications and an intermediate level of python):

Using Ryzen Master's SDK interact with a .dll using python library ctypes (so far this is the closest thing i've found on the internet). I would then call functions from .dll files in the SDK.

So I tried to find some tutorials on it. However, with my limited knowledge on how .dll files work and no experience with C# I thought I'd ask this question.

Please let me know your thoughts, or any advice you may have in this project. I am not asking for someone to do all the work for me. I just need a guide to how this would be acheived by someone with more knowledge of this, and then I will learn the process myself. Thanks for any help!